# Checking processes and running a script if they are down

Tags: python

I'm checking to see if processes are running or not, but when a process is inactive I want to run: `subprocess.run(['/bin/bash','/usr/local/omk/bin/checkomkdaemons.sh','restart'])` - how would I go about putting this into my script so it can run, the command itself works, just need the script to recognize if one of the services is "Inactive" to run the command.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

stat = subprocess.call(["systemctl", "is-active", "--quiet", "omkd"])
if 'stat == 0':  # if 0 (active),print active
 print("omkd Active")
else:
 if 'stat> 0': # if > 0 (active),print inactive
  print("omk Inactive")

stat = subprocess.call(["systemctl", "is-active", "--quiet", "opeventsd"])
if 'stat == 0': # if 0 (active),print active
 print("opeventsd Active")
else
 if 'stat > 0': # if > 0 (active),print inactive
  print("opevents Inactive")
```

Comment: Why are the conditions inside your `if`s strings? For example: `if 'stat == 0'` will always be true. Did you mean `if stat == 0`?

Comment: good, catch.. not sure why I did that..